# number lists in Python

Tags: python

I am allowing choices to user and if the user's choice isn't a number then the script should show an error message: "Please try again".

```
def prompt(message, choices):
  while True:
    choice = input(message)
    if choice in choices:
      return choice
    print("That was not a valid answer. please retry\n"
          "valid answers are", choices)

def aORp():
  choices = list(range(1, 17))
  length= prompt("What is your length? ",choices)
```

Comment: Please, can you clarify what exactly are you asking?

Comment: Please fix the indentation. EDIT : Ty @0xc0de

Comment: I didn't say what was wrong.  I want the user to be able to enter any number but if they don't then it runs  the error message.  All I need is to be able to word the choices =alternative to "list(range(1,17))"  so choices = any number but not a letter or word and if so it runs the error message.

Comment: +1 @klappvisor. To questionner: it's good that you have tried something and shown us, but it's unclear what's your question or problem. Please phrase it like a question (I have fixed your code and saw a bug but I'm not sure if that't your question, so I've let the bug stay in).

Comment: I need an alternative to choices = list(range(1,17)) because any number triggers the error message "That was not a valid answer....."  Obviously the choice of list and range are wrong for what I want to do - which is have the user choose any number but not a string.

Comment: It's because choice is a string while choices is a list of int, so `choice in choices` is always False. You need to convert choice to int.

Comment: This is all the code:

Comment: So you are saying change to int in choices?

Comment: @user2527918 exactly ...if int(choice) in choices:..... But wrap that in a try/except block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a function which inputs a number and then converts it to an int, but doesn't work if it is anything else. If I understand you right, you only want the user to be able to enter an int but not a string. If you only want to check that, an example is:

```
def prompt (message):
    try:
        choice = int(input(message))
        return choice
    except ValueError:
        print("That is not a valid answer, please try again.")
        return prompt(message)
```

That's generally how I do it, but you can definitely use a while loop if you want.

Edit: This allows you to define the choices you want:

```
def prompt (message, choices):
    try:
        choice = int(input(message))
        if choice in choices:
            return choice
        else:
            print("Not a valid input, please try again. \n",
            "Valid inputs are:", (choices))
            return prompt(message, choices)
    except ValueError:
            print("Not a valid input, please try again. \n",
            "Valid inputs are:", choices)
            return prompt(message, choices)
```

Comment: The issue is the line choices = list(range(1,17)) - this doesn't let the user pick a number - instead it says the answer should be [1,2,3,4.....16

Comment: @user2527918 You mean you want every number (int or float) between 1 and 17 to be considered valid ?

Comment: I have added new code in an edit to allow for defining any choices you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys     
def prompt(message, choices):
    while True:
        choice = input(message)
    if choice in choices and type(choice) == int:
        return choice
    else:
        sys.exit("That was not a valid answer. please retry\n"
                 "valid answers are: {}".format(choices))

def aORp():
  choices = list(range(1, 17))
  length= prompt("What is your length? ",choices)
```

by adding the `type(choice) == int` you prevent anything apart from integers to be returned, anything else will result into the termination of the program.

Edit: Maybe you don't your program to terminate on faulty input, but that's up to you!

Edit2: As the comments stated, this doesn't work, actually. Since an answer was given, I'll leave it.

Comment: Im not sure but `type(choice) == int` won't match other numeric types than int. But the questionner asked for all numeric types.

Comment: this does not work. choice is string since it is input by the user so the if statement is always False

Comment: Whoops you are both correct. An answer was already given, I'll write an edit.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to use `float`

```
float(choice)
```

It'll return `True` if choice is a number. It'll return an error if choice is not a number.

More info there :

[How do I check if a string is a number (float) in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354038/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-a-number-float-in-python)

**EDIT** : As mentionned in the comments my answer isn't good, cause `choice` is compared to a `list` of integers then `float` is not the best choice.

Comment: i would go with int(choice) since the list he is comparing against contains items of type integer.

Comment: The questionner said that `choice` has to be a number, that includes `int`  `float` and other numeric types. Or am I missing something ?

Comment: he is checking the number input by the user against a list created using range() so converting the input to float might mess up the comparison performed with "if choice in choices:"

Comment: The issue is the line choices = list(range(1,17)) - this doesn't let the user pick a number - instead it says the answer should be [1,2,3,4.....16]